# Set foreign keys if using a ORM framework

Tags: java, php, sql, orm, doctrine-orm

Do you set foreign keys in your tables although you use an ORM framework like Hibernate or Doctrine? In my opinion the advantage is that you can navigate in the sql admin view easier but I think data integrity is no argument anymore - just because you can set cascade settings in the ORM framework annotations / xml / ...? What do you think?
In my case I will always use foreign keys because it gives me a clean and stable database definition. but I am interested on others opinions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existing ORM (even most powerfull) can be compared to enterprise-ready relational DBMS like mssql, postgres, mysql etc in maintaining data integrity and consistency (feature-wise, perfomance-wise). And your DB managed by RDMBS - is free and extra entry and extensibility point (with many available APIs) for you data. Hence it should keep data consistent while data manipulations, performed by various clients. In many cases you can think of your non-db app as off replacable front-end. Good side effects of being data-centric - you can use your db for low-level synchronisation of your app (app-parts) operations, change your app behavior easily (without client recompilation, redeployment) by changing DB-programmability, schema (including relations, constraints) etc.